# How to configure Android SDK manager with socks?

Tags: java, android, proxy, sdk, socks

The default proxy of Android SDK manager ([android-sdk-manager](/questions/tagged/android-sdk-manager)) is HTTP, but the problem is how can I use it with SOCKS (My OS is Windows 7)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JVM has environment variable for proxy.

[Linux]

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-DsocksProxyHost=<YourProxyHost>"
```

[Windows]

```
set _JAVA_OPTIONS="-DsocksProxyHost=<YourProxyHost>"
```

Default port for socks proxy is 1080, If you are running your proxy in another port you have to tell jvm which port is it.

[Linux]

```
 export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-DsocksProxyHost=<YourProxyHost> -DsocksProxyPort=<YourProxyPort>"
```

[Windows]

```
set _JAVA_OPTIONS="-DsocksProxyHost=<YourProxyHost> -DsocksProxyPort=<YourProxyPort>"
```

And run android sdk manager in current session.

[Linux]

```
 bash /path/to/sdk/tools/android
```

[Windows]

```
 c:\path\to\android.exe
```

You will see something like this at the start:

[Linux]

```
 Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -DsocksProxyHost=<YourProxyHost>
```

Comment: I think for Windows the second command should be `/path/to/sdkmanager.bat`.

Answer (score 0):

[Niknam answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31309657/2593751) is perfect, and I want to add if you use TOR add in your environment

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-DsocksProxyHost=127.0.0.1 -DsocksProxyPort=9050"
```